# How can I resolve the error "the expected type comes from property 'component' which is declared here on type"?

Tags: typescript, react-native

In my code here, I am trying to create a Stack Navigator.

This is the stack navigator I have made.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import EnterPassword from '../screens/EnterPassword';
import EnterAccount from '../screens/EnterAccount';

const GoogleLoginStack = createStackNavigator();

const GoogleLogin = () => {
    return (
        <GoogleLoginStack.Navigator>
            <GoogleLoginStack.Screen name='EnterAccount' component={EnterAccount} />
            <GoogleLoginStack.Screen name='EnterPassword' component={EnterPassword} />
        </GoogleLoginStack.Navigator>
    )
};


export default GoogleLogin;
```

It is then used in App.tsx file where:

```
...
<Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
<GoogleLogin />
<Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
...
```

The screen I have created is as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const EnterAccount = (props: any) =>  {
    <View style={styles.screen}>
        <Text>
            Enter Account Screen
        </Text>
    </View>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
})

export default EnterAccount;
```

However, I am getting this error:
Error text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKbAa.png

I understand that it is because of how I defined the type of props to be but I am unsure of what's the right way to define the type of props.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you haven't returned the JSX for Enter Account component that is why you are getting the error, add return statement in that component

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const EnterAccount = (props: any) =>  {
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
        <Text>
            Enter Account Screen
        </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
})

export default EnterAccount;
```